# (Why) Is it bad practice to check in catkin workspaces?

Tags: ros, catkin, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up a repository which makes it easy for new developers to join the project. To do so I'm considering checking a catkin workspace; doing so without the constituent packages. Are there any known pitfalls to doing this?

Is there a recommended way to create one-step checkout and go setups?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142491/(why)-is-it-bad-practice-to-check-in-catkin-workspaces?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-20**:
What are you actually proposing to check in? My workspace is effectively empty without any packages.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-20**:
My colleges are versioning complete workspaces. There are a few things to take care of. For example that the .rosinstall includes absolute paths, but they successfully versioned workspaces.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-21**:
Be sure to not check in any generated files, such as devel or build folders. Can you motivate what exactly you want to do? It seems by providing a .rosinstall new developers can setup their workspace with just 2-3 commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably not the best solution.

It might be more productive to discuss the problems with the [ROS usability scripts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-usability-scripts).

It should be possible to write a script that creates a workspace and populates it from a rosinstall file all in one command with relatively few required parameters. That would be useful to everyone.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2014-03-21**:
I'm also considering the script option, but am wary that any new adjustments to the setup couldn't be done directly and checked in, but rather would need to be done indirectly in the script and then verified in a fresh checkout. I'm curious about the specific reasons it might be a bad idea.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-21**:
Maybe you could specify what exactly it is that you propose to check in, then we can discuss possible drawbacks or alternatives.